# Searching from a object attribute in a list full of object

Tags: list, python-3.x, class, object, search

I have created a list filled with class objects. Each object has 5 attributes. I need to search for one specific object using its name only:

```
def searchword(list):

    name = str(input("Who are you searching for? Please enter name"))

    for i in list:
        if list[i].name == name:
            print("We found him/her. Here is all information we have on him" + str(list[i]))

        else:
            print("Could not be found. Check spelling!")
```

But I am getting the following error

```
if list[i].name == name:
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Person"
```

Person is the class object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you use:

```
for i in list:
```

you **no not get a list of indices**, you **iterate over the persons** immediately, so `i` is a person here. You can thus use:

```
if i.name == name:
```

instead of:

```
if list[i].name == name:
```

Or in full:

```
def searchword(list):

    name = str(input("Who are you searching for? Please enter name"))

    for i in list:
        if i.name == name:
            print("We found him/her. Here is all information we have on him" + str(i))

        else:
            print("Could not be found. Check spelling!")
```

Furthermore you better name your variables more semantically in Python, so:

```
def searchword(list):

    name = str(input("Who are you searching for? Please enter name"))

    for person in list:
        if person.name == name:
            print("We found him/her. Here is all information we have on him" + str(person))

        else:
            print("Could not be found. Check spelling!")
```